# Create a new Boolean True or False column if a column has a certain string or value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df column below as:

```
Comments
Yes - Verizon
Verizon

Does not contain 
T-Mobile
Standby, call for more
Verizon Software
```

How can I create new column that says `True` or `False` if the `Comments` column contains the word `Verizon` anywhere in that row?

Expected Output:

```
Comments         |  Has Verizon?
Yes - Verizon          True
Verizon                True
                       False
Does not contain       False
T-Mobile               False
Standby, call for more False
Verizon Software       True
```

Comment: you need to accses the Comment colluom and i would say make a while or for loop to check if the word contain the value you want and to return a Flase or True use ```return True``` for example

Comment: no. A loop is NOT the way to go. Ami's answer is the proper Pandas method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.Comments.str.contains('Verizon')`

should do it. This causes to apply [the string-column method `contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: A small expansion: `contains("V|verizon", regex=True)` will allow for capitalization differences.

Comment: @noah do you mean that would account for Verizon and Verizon accepting both as true?

Comment: I think you mean "Verizon" and "verizon", but yes. It will call both true

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with list comprehensions, then you can do the same to your datafram columns:

```
df['Comments'] = [True if 'Verizon' in x else False for x in df['Comments']]
```

Though this is not very efficient, @Ami Tavory's answer is spot on.